# I am getting an error when trying to click on Like button This page isn’t working HTTP ERROR 405

Tags: html, python-3.x, django, post

I am new to Django and trying to implemet Like and Dislike option in Blog application.

I have issue where once any logged in user click Like button the browser gives **HTTP ERROR 405**

Once user click Like button it redirect to PostDetailView (post_detail)

I have also added POST in form method as below in post_detail.html page

**view.py**

```html
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'blog/post_detail.html'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        data = get_object_or_404(Post, id=self.kwargs['pk'])
        total_likes = data.total_likes()
        liked = False
        if data.likes.filter(id=self.request.user.id).exists():
            liked = True
        else:
            pass
        context["total_likes"] = total_likes
        context["liked"] = liked
        return context
        
def LikeView(request,pk):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
        liked = False
        if post.likes.filter(id=request.user.id).exists():
            post.likes.remove(request.user)
        else:
            post.likes.add(request.user)
            liked = True
        post.likes.add(request.user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[str(pk)]))
```

**post_detail.html**

```html
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <article class="media content-section">
        <img class="rounded-circle article-img" src="{{ object.author.profile.image.url }}">
        <div class="media-body">
            <div class="article-metadata">
                <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'user_post' object.author.username %}">{{ object.author }}</a>
                <small class="text-muted">{{ object.date_posted }}</small>
            </div>
            <h2 class="article-title">{{ object.title }}</h2>
            <p class="article-content">{{ object.content|urlize }}</p>
            {% if object.author == user %}
                    <div>
                        <a class="btn sm btn btn-secondary mb-1" href="{% url 'post_update' object.id %}">Update</a>
                        <a class="btn sm btn btn-danger mb-1" href="{% url 'post_delete' object.id %}">Delete</a>
                    </div>
            {% endif %}
            
            <br/><br/>
            <form action="{% url 'like_post' object.id %}" 
                method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {% if liked %}
                    <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" type="submit", name "post_id", value={{post.id}}>Unlike
                    </button>
                {% else %}
                    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit", name "post_id", value={{post.id}}>Like
                    </button>
                {% endif %}
                 - {{ total_likes }}
            </form>

        </div>
    </article>
    
{% endblock  %}
```

**urls.py**

```html
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user_post'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post_update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post_delete'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreateView.as_view(), name='post_create'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('contact/', views.contactView, name='contact'),
    path('success/', views.successView, name='success'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.LikeView, name='like_post'),
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your urls.py
"like_post" and "post_detail"
have the same pattern.I think your code chooses "post_detail" instead of "like_post" when you post to this url.

```py
urlpatterns = [
    path('post/<int:pk>/like', views.LikeView, name='like_post'),
]
```

can solve you problem

Comment: It shows error as "TemplateDoesNotExist at /post/12/like", Once user clicked Like button I am redirecting it to post_detail page using 
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[str(pk)]))

Comment: I resloved this by changing LikeView pattern in urls.py, I didn't notice that there are same url pattern.